# Angular 8 get details about every user loop over firestore collection

Tags: angular, firebase, for-loop

I have a firestore collection called 'stars' which has: userId, teacherId, documentId and some values.
What i'm trying to do is for each star to get the details about its teacher. (They are in another collection 'users').

I have this method to get all stars (This works):

```
    getAllStars(idDocument: string): void {
        this.dataApi.getAllStars(idDocument).subscribe(stars => {
          this.stars = stars;
      }
```

I have this method to get the details for every teacher (This works):

```
  getTeacherDetails(id: string): void {
    this.dataApi.getOneUser(id).subscribe(teacher => {
        this.teacher = teacher;
    });
   }
```

What i don't know is how to use a for loop in the getAllStars method to get the details about each teacher. I thought about something like this: this.getTeacherDetails(this.star.teacherId) but don't know how to implement this.
Can you help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you please add the JSON data from the collection, to your question?

Comment: I solved the problem thanks to @Manish. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I would suggest to modify the API instead to get the data in one go if possible, here is how you can loop through `stars` and get details of each teacher and possibly store it in a property `teacher` in `star` only.

```
getAllStars(idDocument: string): void {
    this.dataApi.getAllStars(idDocument).subscribe(stars => {
      this.stars = stars;
      for (let index = 0; index < this.stars.length; index++) {
        const star = this.stars[index];
        this.dataApi.getOneUser(star.teacherId).subscribe(teacher => {
          star.teacher = teacher;
        });
      } 
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use RxJS [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/forkJoin) with [`switchMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/switchMap) operator to handle the multiple observables. Having nested subscriptions, especially in a loop isn't good practice. Try the following

```js
import { forkJoin, pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

getAllTeachers(idDocument: string) {
  this.dataApi.getAllStars(idDocument).pipe(
    switchMap(stars => {
      this.stars = stars;
      return forkJoin(stars.map(star => this.dataApi.getOneUser(star['teacherId'])))
    })
    .subscribe(
      teachers => {
        this.stars = this.stars.map((star, i) => Object.assign({}, star, { teacher: teachers[i] }));
      },
      error => { 
        // handle error
      }
    );
}
```